# getting duplicate terms in list in java

Tags: java

what's wrong in code? am not getting any values in output. but it should print duplicate values. (`a` is a `Arraylist`)

```
HashSet<Integer> hs=new HashSet();
hs.addAll(a);
List<Integer> b=new ArrayList();
a.removeAll(hs);
System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: What is variable `b` doing in this? It seems to be pointless.

Comment: You literally removed all the elements from a. Of course a is empty.

Comment: *but it should print duplicate values* - why is that? You mean it should print the values that were previously duplicates?

Comment: Do a System.out.println(a); Before creating the hashset. That will verify the data. It won't print duplicate data but it should print everything in a.

Comment: *ping* did any of the answers help you? Consider leaving feedback or accepting the answer the solved the problem / resolved your confusion / answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you think that `a.removeAll(hs);` remove every element at most once. That is not the case. As [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)) state:

> [...] After this call returns, this collection will contain no elements in common with the specified collection

That means that even though `hs.addAll(a);` will result in a Set containing potentially less values than `a` (missing the duplicates) calling `a.removeAll(hs)` will still remove all the original values as well as the duplicates.

The source code of `removeAll` verifies that as it iterates over `a` and checks wether or not a element of `a` is in `hs` and removes it from `a` if that is the case. It does not iterate over `hs` and removes a matching element of `a`. [Source grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#349)

Answer (score 0):

What you could use is `removeIf`:

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,7)); 

Map<Integer, List<Integer>> counter = a.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i));
a.removeIf(v -> counter.get(v).size() == 1);
System.out.println(new HashSet<Integer>(a)); //[1, 2, 3, 6]
```